# video player open source or build my own

Tags: flash, html5-video, media-player, video-player

i am working on a video hosting website where i need a video player and i was wondering if there is any open source player available without logo/royality or any such kind of marks on the player .
and should i use them or build my own like other sites.
and also i dont know what language to code for a video player ?

some basic functionality that i need from the player is that play/paue sound and hd off/on button.

i know there are may like jwplayer and others availabe but they have logo and other stuffes and also i dont know how to use them.

i just want a brief description or any linlk where i can read about this.
please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search for ffmpeg and then use html5 or jwplayer